WorldPay Payment method REST API for Transaction/Payment details in Magento 2.4.7
Has anyone worked with the WorldPay Payment Method API?
I've successfully installed the WorldPay Payment Method, but I'm struggling to find the API for retrieving transaction or payment details. Specifically, I need to check the status of transactions so I can perform certain operations based on that information.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

The worldpay send its transaction details in notification instantly after payment done. Please check your notification url (webhook) is configured or not in worldpay portal.

Going through the module source I observed the file https://github.com/Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Syncstatus/Index.php that contains code to sync the status of payment for specific order in admin area but if you want you can use the same code on frontend for your purpose. You can check the below functions
$this->_fetchPaymentUpdate();
$this->_registerWorldPayModel();
$this->_applyPaymentUpdate();
$this->_updateOrderStatus();
$this->_applyTokenUpdate();

If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.
Happy Coding
